# CSS menu text wrapping

Tags: css, menu, word-wrap

I want to show a menu within regular text, so that the text wraps around my menu.
Any suggestions guys?

The menu with text:

```
This is some text with an <ul id="ddmenu"><li><a href="#">option link</a><ul class="ddsubmenu"><li><div id="ddmenudiv">and a second</div></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Using the div containing the submenu item to make the background going over the regular text.

My css:

```
/*Init */

ul#ddmenu, ul#ddmenu ul.ddsubmenu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#ddmenu li, ul#ddmenu ul.ddsubmenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#ddmenu li a, ul#ddmenu li ul.ddsubmenu li a {
    text-decoration: bold;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#ddmenu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#ddmenu li ul.ddsubmenu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#ddmenu li:hover ul.ddsubmenu {
    display:block;
}
#ddmenudiv {
   background: #fff;
   z-index: 999; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you are asking, but I think this may be the solution you are looking for:

Simply add `display: inline-block;` to your `ul#ddmenu, ul#ddmenu ul.ddsubmenu` properties, as I've done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G5Ku3/2/).

HTML:

```
This is some text with an 
    <ul id="ddmenu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">option link</a>
            <ul class="ddsubmenu">
                <li>
                    <div id="ddmenudiv">and a second</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#ddmenu, ul#ddmenu ul.ddsubmenu {
padding:0;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
ul#ddmenu li, ul#ddmenu ul.ddsubmenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Link Appearance*/
ul#ddmenu li a, ul#ddmenu li ul.ddsubmenu li a {
    text-decoration: bold;
    display:inline-block;
}

/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#ddmenu li {
    position: relative;
}

/*sub menu*/
ul#ddmenu li ul.ddsubmenu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#ddmenu li:hover ul.ddsubmenu {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I tried it but it gives me 3 seperate lines, instead what I want is "regular text" directly followed by the dropdown (whithour linebreak), and then directly followed by more text

Answer (score 0):

Thx for  the reply! When I do this I get:

```
This is some text with an
option link
and some more text
```

While what I need is:

```
This is some text with an option link and some more text
```

So basically the dropdown would look like regular text inbetween the rest of the regular text, but once someone hovers over, it would show options. Intend to give a user certain options on specific terms (like "Search Google for xyz".